# External reference Python

Tags: python

I'm using a python script that will be run when one of my several services becomes down. It uses several external parameters from the monitoring system such as {HOST.NAME}, which would be transformed into 'Ubuntu 1' for example.

Because I'm intending to send both a plaintext and HTML-email, this needs to be configured in the script itself. I'm particularly new to Python, so I'm not sure how to refference these objects. The e-mail itself works, but the given parameters aren't read correctly.  This is what I have so far.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

list1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

import mimetypes, os, smtplib, sys
from email import encoders
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email.utils import make_msgid


me = "xx@yy.com"
you = "yy@xx.com"
DESTINATION=sys.argv[1]
SUBJECT=sys.argv[2]
MESSAGE=sys.argv[3]
PASS='xxyyxx'
SRVSMTP='somesmtpserver:587'

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
msg['Date'] = formatdate()
msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()

hostnam= '{HOST.NAME}'
trgname= '{TRIGGER.NAME}'
trgstat= '{TRIGGER.STATUS}'
trgseve= '{TRIGGER.SEVERITY}'

text = """A problem has been detected on 'hostnam' \n \n Trigger: 'trgname' \n Status: 'trgstat' \n Severity: 'trgseve' \n \n Om een vervangende bestelling te plaatsen voor 'hostnam' , wordt u verzocht om een e-mail verzenden met daar in de naam van het product naar het e-mail adres EMAIL2@LIAME.nl \n
Dit bericht is automatisch gegenereerd door het Zabbix Notification system.\n Er wordt niet gereageerd op dit e-mail adres. \n
"""
html = """
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img alt="Related image" src="imagehere" /></p>

<p style="margin-left: 40px;">Er is een probleem opgetreden bij<strong>&nbsp; 'hostnam'</strong>&nbsp;.</p>

<p style="margin-left: 80px;"><strong>Trigger:</strong> 'trgname'<br />
<strong>Status</strong>: 'trgstat' <br />
<strong>Severity:</strong> 'trgseve' |</p>

<p style="margin-left: 40px;"><a href="mailto:xxyyxx@aa.com">Klik hier</a> om een vervangende bestelling te plaatsen voor de&nbsp;<strong>'hostnam'.</strong><br />
&nbsp;</p>


<p style="margin-left: 40px;"><span style="font-size:9px;">Dit bericht is automatisch gegenereerd, er zal op dit e-mail adres niet worden gereageerd.<br />
&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP(SRVSMTP)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(me, PASS)


# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
smtpserver.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
smtpserver.quit()
```

Comment: *The given parameters aren't read correctly* (and by *correctly* you mean *as I intend*). What exactly is happening, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: Apologies for my poor choice of words. The values given by 'Zabbix', which is the monitoring system I use, are as followed. 

{TRIGGER.NAME} should display the string of the name of the trigger that went off. Such as 'Disk space below 20%'. Because I'm using both HTML and Plaintext emails, I need to find a way to attach the result that is given by Zabbix to a single word for example.

Comment: What I intended to do here is attach the result '{HOST.NAME}' to the term 'hostnam'.

Comment: I seem to be missing something crucial here. Is `TRIGGER` a variable you haven't shown us? It's not defined in the code I see. How does the value of `TRIGGER` get from Zabbix into your program?

Comment: It is not defined in the code. The definition comes from the monitoring system, which is able to send a message on it's own. This information _should_ be forwarded by Zabbix, before the script is run.

Comment: Comes *how*? How does the monitoring system get it into your program? Is Python embedded in the product? Is it reading your Python source and modifying it? Is it setting it up in a global variable and then `exec`ing your source? Or what?

Comment: It's possible to write the message on it's own in Zabbix. Which would then be relayed to a mailing service. This is what I intended to do first. But that's where I learned it'd be either or HTML e-mail or plain-text only. Now, it only sends a "message" that includes these four parameters. {HOST.NAME} {TRIGGER.NAME} {TRIGGER.SEVERITY} {TRIGGER.STATUS}.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain _how_ to import these values into the code. That's the issue I'm running in to. 

It doesn't read the file as far as I'm aware. It only executes the script.

Comment: From my brief look at the documentation, Zabbix executes a command line that runs your program and passes it the alert data. So your Python program needs to get the parameters from the command line when it runs. Use the module `argparse` for that.